# How do I check for reference equality in F#?

Tags: f#, equality

F# uses structural equality for the `=` operator, which is almost always what you want:

```
let a = [1; 2; 3]
let b = [1; 2; 3]
printfn "%A" (a = b)  // Prints "true"
```

But in some algorithms, it can be important to be able to ask "Are these two things *the same object*?" This can help with detecting cycles in a graph, for example. So how do I ask for reference equality in F#? I.e., how do I write the `isSameObject` function below?

```
let isSameObject x y = ???
let a = [1; 2; 3]
let b = [1; 2; 3]
let a' = a
printfn "%A" (isSameObject a b)  // Prints "false"
printfn "%A" (isSameObject a a')  // Prints "true"
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is to use [`LanguagePrimitives.PhysicalEquality`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/languageprimitives.physicalequality%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
let isSameObject = LanguagePrimitives.PhysicalEquality
let a = [1; 2; 3]
let b = [1; 2; 3]
let a' = a
printfn "%A" (isSameObject a b)  // Prints "false"
printfn "%A" (isSameObject a a')  // Prints "true"
```

There was precisely one question I could find on Stack Overflow that asked about this:
[short-cutting equality checking in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686216/short-cutting-equality-checking-in-f) And since that question's subject almost made me glance right past it, I figured I would ask (and answer) the question again. Hopefully this question's subject line will make it easier to find when Googling for terms like "referential equality in F#".

**What about `obj.ReferenceEquals`?**

In a comment, Fyodor Soikin asks what's wrong with `obj.ReferenceEquals`. The answer is "not much", but there are two ways in which `LanguagePrimitives.PhysicalEquality` is better than `obj.ReferenceEquals` for most F# code:

1) `PhysicalEquality` throws a compiler error when you pass it two different types, while `obj.ReferenceEquals` just takes two `obj`s and therefore happily tries to compare an `int list` to `char list`:

```
let a = [1;2;3]
let b = ['a';'b';'c']

obj.ReferenceEquals(a,b) // Returns false
LanguagePrimitives.PhysicalEquality a b // Compiler error
```

2) `PhysicalEquality` won't let you compare value types, only reference types. `obj.ReferenceEquals` will let you compare two value types, and will implicitly box them first. But it boxes each one separately, meaning that it will *always* return false even when you gave it the "same" value object:

```
let n = 3
let n' = n
obj.ReferenceEquals(n,n') // Returns false!
LanguagePrimitives.PhysicalEquality n n' // Compiler error
```

And, of course, there's one other difference, which boils down to personal preference and ease-of-use. `PhysicalEquality` takes curried-style parameters, which plays nicely with type inference and partial application. `obj.ReferenceEquals` takes tupled-style parameters, which means it's slightly uglier to use.

For all these reasons, `LanguagePrimitives.PhysicalEquality` is better to use, in *almost* every scenario, than `obj.ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - I wrote two comments in response to your question, then realized that they'd be better in the answer, with code examples. So there you go: `obj.ReferenceEquals` isn't **bad**, but `PhysicalEquality` is better because it will give you type errors if you try to compare two different types. (Which is almost certainly a bug in your code, and you *want* the compiler to help you catch it).